# RequireJS QCodeDecoder exports Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, django, requirejs

I'm trying to implement requirejs in my django project using qcode-decoder as one of the libs (https://github.com/cirocosta/qcode-decoder/blob/master/src/qcode-decoder.js).
In html i'm doing this:

```
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/libs/require.js"></script>
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/pages/pay_iframe.js"></script>
```

And this is my pay_iframe.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/static/js/pages',
    paths: {
        qcode_decoder: '../libs/qcode/qcode-decoder',
        porthole: '../libs/porthole',
        jquery: '../libs/jquery',
        pay_iframe: 'pay_iframe',
    },
    shim: {
        'qcode_decoder': {
            exports: 'QCodeDecoder',
        },
        'pay_iframe': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'qcode_decoder', 'porthole'],
        },
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'qcode_decoder', 'porthole'], function($, QCodeDecoder) {
    console.log(QCodeDecoder);
    var qr = new QCodeDecoder();
    if (!(qr.isCanvasSupported() && qr.hasGetUserMedia())) {
        ...
    }
    ...
});
```

Everything seems to load fine, in the right order but when I try to create QCodeDecoder object (which worked before implementing requirejs btw) i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

I guess it is because QCodeDecoder is an object (as printed by console.log):

```
Object {imagedata: null, width: 0, height: 0, qrCodeSymbol: null, debug: false…}
```

However this object does not contain functions used later (isCanvasSupported and hasGetUserMedia) so I cannot just do that:

```
var qr = QCodeDecoder;
```

It does not work either.
Maybe I should export (in shim config) something else? 
Please help me out.

Comment: Seems my QCodeDecoder is AMD, so the export is not needed anyway. It does not solve my problem though.

Comment: You should edit your question to take into account your discovery. People don't always pay attention to comments. Moreover comments are ephemeral. They can be deleted by moderators at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `require` to `define` solves it.